# Install Intel 10 Gigabit AT2 Server Adapter Server 2012

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, intel

I'm attempting to install an Intel 10 Gigabit Ethernet AT2 Server Adapter into a machine, running Server 2012 R2.

Hardware Information:

PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_150B&SUBSYS_A12C8086&REV_01
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_150B&SUBSYS_A12C8086
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_150B&CC_020000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_150B&CC_0200

The card itself works fine in Server 2008R2. I've placed in another computer to verify that the card is not faulty.  On Intel's website, it's shown as a Server 2012 support card:
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000006476.html

Intel® 10 Gigabit AT2 Server Adapter with box inbox, and full support.

I've searched the Intel website for the drivers, and found the following:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/50266/Intel-10-Gigabit-AT2-Server-Adapter

But I can't seem to find the correct server 2012 drivers.  If I attempt installation of server 2008 drivers or various other ProSet 2012 drivers , the installer package says: Cannot install drivers. No Intel Adapters are present in this computer.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is this particular card on this list? If not, then I don't know why you'd be trying to install an unsupported card. - http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products/000005768.html

Comment: Yes, under this section: PCI-Express* Intel® 10 Gigabit Ethernet Server Adapters with Intel® 82598 Ethernet Controller:

Comment: Does your card have that controller? I couldn't find an R2 driver for that card.

Comment: Here is exact card: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106043
It states: Intel 82598EB for the CPU / Controller.  I'm still unable to locate a driver for this card..